# Should the preposition "of" always follow the verb "to approve"?

Tags: verbs, prepositions

When one says "The novel approves of the character's behaviour", the preposition "of" is compulsory. But when one says "The novel approves of the ideology" is the preposition compulsory? Is this preposition always used after the verb "to approve"?

Comment: _Approve_ and _approve of_ don't mean the same thing, though they can both be true at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the [BBC.co.uk](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv26.shtml) site, ***approve and approve of*** convey different meanings:

> ***The meaning of approve changes when you add the preposition of to make approve of***.
>
> ***Approve'by itself means 'sanction' or 'endorse'*** as in these two examples. In the first, an accountant is speaking and in the second, a university admissions tutor.
>
> - *'I cannot approve the reimbursement because you haven't given me the receipts for your expenditure.'*
> - *'I cannot approve your application to study law because you do not have the relevant qualifications.'*
>
> ***If you approve of something, then you consider it to be good or you agree with it.*** Consider:
>
> - *'I don't approve of smoking in restaurants because it is so upsetting usually for non-smokers.'*
> - *'Why don't you approve of my friends? They are all good upright * people.'